# Excel formula to tell difference between 0.00 and 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of numbers that I need to count, however I need to count the 0.00 but not the 0's. For example:

```
0
0.00
2.85
6.68
1.35
3.27
5.24
5.42
3.32
7.20
0
0
```

I would need this to count 9 and exclude the three 0's

I have tried using a `COUNTIF` formula but it seems to be treating the `0.00` and `0` in the same way which isn't giving me the result I need.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm unable to think of any other way around this.

Answer (score 1):

If you format the list of numbers as Text then the `COUNTIF` formula will respect the difference between 0 and 0.00. See this example below.

Both `B1` and `E1` have a similar formula:

```
=COUNTIF(D1:D12,"<>0")
```

But the range `D1:D12` has been given a format of text and so includes the 0.00 therefore giving the answer you want - 9.

[image]